# Android 2.2 localstorage

Tags: android, local-storage

In android 2.2 i'm not able to retrieve local storage value after the application is force closed.IF you have any suggestion...Please take look at my code:

```
    WebSettings  ws= appView.getSettings();
    ws.setDatabasePath("/data/data/com.decodeSoutions.hive/app_database");
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setDatabaseEnabled(true);                                                                                                                       
    ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. At first I load my data with .loadDataWithBaseURL() with assets dir as base url and there is the problem. In Android 2.1 this works fine with setDomStorageEnabled(true) but in 2.2 you have todo the following.

At first:

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName()+"/databases/");
```

Now the tricky part beginns:

Write all the html code to a file because the "loadData"-functions disable the localstorage in some way.

```
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("test.html", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(yourHTMLString.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    webView.loadUrl("file://" + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/test.html");
```

But be carefull if you load css or js relative in your html, because your basepath is not set. To fix this enter "file:///android_assets/" to your html code e.g:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/${stylesheet}" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/js/jstorage.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps someone. It costs me hours!